# Store the rank of generated input fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I’m stuck on something that I can’t fix by myself :( Unfortunately… I need to store a rank from some inputs fields generated by jQuery in my TABLE, let me explain :

When I click on a button I add an input field in my page, each input field generated have an incremented name (name0, name1 ...) and an incremented id (item-1, item-2 and so on)

I use the sortable function of jQuery and everything is okay, I drag and drop my fields and they have their order.

I serialize everything and it gives me that : item[]=0&item;[]=2&item;[]=1&item;[]=3 each field have a rank. Well now I need to store this rank in my DB WITH the field associated (my TABLE look like this : ‘id’ ‘rank’ the ‘id field is auto incremented)

Here’s my code :

THE JS FUNCTION TO ADD FIELDS :

```
$(function() {

 var item = 'item-';
 var i = 0;
 var k = 0;
 var deletebtn = "<div id='deletebtn'>delete this</div>";

 $("#button_add").live("click", function(){
   $('#reorder').append("<li id="+ item + i++ +" class='list_item'>" + "<input type='text' name='title"+ k++ +"' value='' kind='title' />" + deletebtn + "</li>");
 });
});
```

TO GET THE SERIALIZE RESULT :

```
newRank = $("#reorder").sortable("serialize");
 $("#rank").val(newRank);
```

This is linked to an input field to get the serialized value

```
<input type="hidden" id="rank" name="rank" value="" />
```

THE PHP TO $_POST THE INPUT FIELD :

```
    $rank = $this->input->post('rank'); 

// THIS WILL GIVE ME THE RESULT : item[]=0&item;[]=2&item;[]=1&item;[]=3
```

Any idea to store the rank of each field corresponding to their id in my DB ? Any help would be very very appreciated !!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow... Please don't put tags (`[jQuery, PHP]`) in the title. That's what the actual tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you could of course create an array from `$rank` and loop through for your db inserts:

```
$ranks = explode("&", $rank); // gives an array 

foreach ($ranks as $r)
{
    // you'll have to do some string manipulation here
    $num = str_replace("item[]=", "", $r);

    // $num should now be a number - add it to your db below
    // ...
}
```

There are some extra semi-colons in your $rank, but not sure if that is a typo or not.